# If we have Y=β0 + β1D + U, where D is a dummy variable that can be either 0 or 1, how do we prove the estimators of β0 and β1?

Tags: regression, self-study, estimators

Specifically, how do we show β0 is  ȳ0 and the estimator of β1=  ȳ1- ȳ0 if we know how OLS estimators are normally supposed to be?

ȳ1 and ȳ0 are the mean of y1 and y0.

I started off with Σ(Di-D̄)yi/Σ(Di-D̄)^2 but I'm not sure about what D̄ is supposed to represent or how you are supposed to get ȳ1 and ȳ0.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by $\bar{y}_0$ and $\bar{y}_1$?  Because this looks like a self-study problem (you already have the answer), then please apply the [tag:self-study] tag and read over its tag wiki at https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: ¯0  and ¯1 are the mean of y0 and y1.

Comment: Do you mean $\bar{y}_i$ is the mean of $y$ *conditional* on $D=i$?

Answer (score 0):

So you have $y = X\beta + U$ where $X = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ with $n_1$ 0's and $n_2$ 1's in the dummy variable vector.
Then, find $\begin{bmatrix} \hat{\beta}_{0} \\ \hat{\beta}_{1}\end{bmatrix}=\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$.

Note that $X'X = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 0 & \cdots & 0 &  1 &\cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}n & n_2 \\ n_2 & n_2\end{bmatrix}$, so $(X'X)^{-1}=\frac{1}{n_2*(n-n_2)}\begin{bmatrix}n_2 & -n_2 \\ -n_2 & n\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{n_2*n_1}\begin{bmatrix}n_2 & -n_2 \\ -n_2 & n\end{bmatrix}$.

Moreover, $X'y=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 0 & \cdots & 0 &  1 &\cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}  * \begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\\ \sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i \end{bmatrix}$.

Putting it all together, we attain:

$(X'X)^{-1}X'y=\frac{1}{n_2*n_1}\begin{bmatrix}n_2 & -n_2 \\ -n_2 & n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\\ \sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{n_2*n_1}\begin{bmatrix}n_2*\sum_{i=1}^n y_i - n_2*\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i\\ n*\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i - n_2*\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{n_2*n_1}\begin{bmatrix}n_2*\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i \\ n*\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i - n_2*\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i - n_2 * \sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{n_2*n_1}\begin{bmatrix}n_2*\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i \\ n_1*\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i - n_2*\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \bar{y}_{n_1} \\ \bar{y}_{n_2}-\bar{y}_{n_1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \hat{\beta}_{0} \\ \hat{\beta}_{1}\end{bmatrix}$

I hope this answers your question.